# Passing a param from javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

I have the following javascript in a View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pusher = new Pusher('<%= Pusher.key %>'); // Replace with your app key
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('choices');

    channel.bind('created', function(data) {
        var after = $('.ticket:last').attr('data-time');
        $("#tickets").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@tickets, :after => " + after + ")) %>");
    });
</script>
```

And the following in my Controller:

```
@tickets  = Choice.where("choices.created_at > ?", Time.at(params[:after].to_i + 1).utc)
```

I'm looking for a way to pass the **after** param from the javascript to the controller, så it only returns the Choices where the created_at are higher then the last Choice displayed right now.

I guees this line ain't doing the job, so a bit of help with this would very much appriciated :)

```
$("#tickets").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@tickets, :after => " + after + ")) %>");
```

**EDIT:**

I now have the following, which seems to fix the passing of the **after** variable to the controller.. I checked Firebug and can see the response conteains the data on the newest BET.. But the view is still wrong. Instead of appending the newest Bet to the DIV it shows all the past BETS twice without the new one at all. Anyone? :)

View file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pusher = new Pusher('<%= Pusher.key %>'); // Replace with your app key
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('choices');

    channel.bind('created', function(data) {
        var after = $('.ticket:last').attr('data-time');

        var settings = { after: after}
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: settings,
            cache: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tickets").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@tickets)) %>");
                }
          });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Routes:

```
post 'Home/Index' => 'home#index'
```

Controller (Index action):

```
@tickets  = Choice.betable(current_user).where("choices.created_at > ?", Time.at(params[:after].to_i + 1).utc)

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @tickets }
  format.html
end
```

Solution:

After a lot of trial and error I ended up using a solution, where I render the HTML in the controller instead of in the javescript code in the view. In that way I have access to the params I needed.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html      
  format.json do
    @html = render_to_string( :partial => '/choices/choice.html.erb', :locals => { :choice => @tickets} )
    render :json => { :success => true, :html => @html }
  end
end
```

Thanks to Chazt3n for the extended help :) Really appriciated it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could send it via AJAX

```
Function sendAfter((string?) after){
 var settings = { after: after}
 $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: settings,
        cache: true,
        success: function (data) {}
      });
}
```

This will get your data through to the controller at least
Just call that function and send it your parameter wherever you want it

Comment: the after on the right side of the ":" is your after, the first is the name of the object you'll send as a param to the action.

Comment: Could you combine your code with my code, cause I don't know were to place your code within the code I have :) Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, when is your code executed? is it on a click event?

Comment: I'm using Pusher (websocket) to trigger the event. This is triggered just fine, but I can't seem to get the after param along to to controller.

Comment: I've turned it into a function, try placing that as soon as you want that param sent in and it should work just fine. now is :After a string or an object? I'm sorry I'm half working and half trying to be helpful at the moment, I'll have more time after 5 here.

Comment: I tried to incorporate your code in my code on the top of the page (in my question).. it doesn't work.. can you see what I should do?

Comment: sorry for the late response.. but what is the NET Panel? But how do I combine your code with `$("#tickets").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@tickets, :after => " + after + ")) %>");`.

Comment: Do I need a specefic route to make thsi work. Here i'm thinking of the URL parameter, which in my case is '/home/index'.

Comment: Firefox's Firebug, there's a panel called the NET panel, and the CONSOLE will tell you any errors, I'm sorry I haven't been much help I've been absolutely slammed at work, I'll look again at 12

Comment: Not to worry.. really appriciate the help and very thankful for anyone who will help out newbies like me :)

Comment: and it will be /Home/Index if the Index action is inside the HomeController btw

Comment: nevermind... just lookedat var after = $('.ticket:last').attr('data-time');

Comment: I just edited my question with the code I got.. so close now :)

Comment: Yes Firebug says that the POST response only contains the newly created BET, which is correct.. But when it is rendered the HTML contains only the old BETS, but not only once, but twice after each other.. It seems it appends all BETS, but leaves out the one that I actually want to append.. does it make sense?

Comment: if I try to use `logger.debug "Tickets: #{@tickets.to_yaml}"` I can see that the @tickets variable only contains the newly created BET, which is correct.. Can figure out where this goes wrong then.

Comment: Does the page refresh? Or maybe the Socket is getting triggered more than once if it's in the $(document).ready() So it's sending the correct data to the controller and the controller is sending the correct data back. We just need to plug that in right?

Comment: The new ticket should be inside the data object (accessible from the success function) It seems that the ` <%=raw escape_javascript(render(@tickets)) %>` just displays the old. The new BET needs to be added

Maybe $("#Tickets").append(data);

Comment: Yes that's also the conclusion that I have made.. that the `<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@tickets)) %>` needs to contain the new Bet and not the old ones.. How do we do that then :)

Comment: If I try `console.log(data)` it also contains the correct BET.. can see how to connect the data variable to the rendered @tickets..?

Comment: can you show me the json string returned from your controller please?

Comment: Hi again :) I don't hope I'm keeping you to much away from your work.. but the returned json string looks like this: `[{"created_at":"2012-10-18T19:00:12+02:00","deliverydate":"2012-10-19","exposure":80,"id":115,"product_id":2,"profitloss":0,"settled":false,"spotarea_id":2,"updated_at":"2012-10-18T19:00:12+02:00","user_id":2,"value":1100}]`

Comment: And I guess that the json string somehow should be stuffed into the `$("#tickets").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@tickets)) %>");` code, so when the partial is rendered it's using the json string as input.. but how I can't seem to figure out.. Maybe the `@tickets` should be replaced with something like `/choices/choice` which is tha actual partial..

Comment: That would be fine, or make sure that data is getting inside the Partial so when it's loaded you'll see the old and new?

Comment: I can't seem to get it right.. Is it possible to render the entire partial in the controller and then pass all the HTML along as the ajax response. How can one do that maybe?

Comment: I think I got it now.. look at the last edit to my question.. Thanks a lot for the help.. :)

Comment: I'm glad, thank you for marking my answer and I'm sorry I took so long to get back to you